# How do I specify the platform with chef-gem?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-zero

Usually you install a platform-dependant gem like this:

gem install sys-proctable -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "0.9.3" --platform mswin32

How do I pass the --platform parameter with chef_gem?

Best,

-Iulian

Comment: Do you need to specify a platform for `chef gem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure I answered you on IRC, but for the future you would use `options '--platform mswin32'`. That said, binary gems are flaky at best so expect to run into complications eventually.

Comment: Not sure if you did on IRC, but thank you anyway. As a form of feedback,(in addition to speaking about the difficulties the users are having with the  documentation/manual, stuff that I see over most forums and a couple of conversations we had with you guys earlier this year at AWS Summit LNDN) that would be something I would expect from the documentation. One of the most pleasant documentation implementation was http://php.net. Loads of examples, with user feedback on how to avoid certain tricky cases or short howto's.

Comment: You say "you guys" in a way that makes me think you think I work for Chef, I do not.